# Spring application runs but cannot create beans on test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm writing an application with Spring and I want to use Unit tests.
When I'm running my Application, no Error or Exception occurs. But when I want to run 'gradle test' there are UnsatisifiedDependencyExceptions all over the place.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AuthenticationController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockMvc.class, TokenHandler.class, LoginService.class, UserService.class})
public class AuthenticationControllerTest {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired private TokenHandler tokenHandler;
    @Autowired private LoginService loginService;
    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    @Value("${server.port}") private Integer serverPort;

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    private UserEntity userEntity;
    private String token;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.username = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.email = this.username + "@test.com";
        this.password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void a0_register() throws Exception {
        RegisterDTO registerDTO = new RegisterDTO();
        registerDTO.setUsername(this.username);
        registerDTO.setEmail(this.email);
        registerDTO.setPassword(this.password);

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI.create("/authentication/register"))
                    .content(JSON.asJsonString(registerDTO))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("0"));

        this.userEntity = this.userService.findAll().stream().filter(e->e.getEmail().equals(email)).findFirst().orElse(null);

        assertNotNull(userEntity);
    }
}
```

Here is an example for one of the Exceptions which are thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.roomono.administration.Database.Repository.Log.LoginRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
... 67 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line needs to be fixed:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockMvc.class, TokenHandler.class, LoginService.class, UserService.class})
```

Don't list the service or bean classes here. Instead, create a configuration class to configure the beans. Such as:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public LoginService loginService() {
    return new LoginService();
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, use it:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
```

Comment: I have much more testclasses in the future. Is it possible to use '@ComponentScan(basePackages={com.company.example})' to make things easier?

Comment: Not really. ComponentScan tells Spring where to look for components, but does not tell Spring how to create beans from those components. Still need to write configuration to create beans. Unless you find another way :)